# Django validators RegexValidator does not show custom message when field is incorrect

Tags: django

I need to add `RegexValidator` to `URLField`. It works, but I want to customize it's message. 
I added parameter `message` with my custom text, but it still shows

`Enter a valid URL." instead of my text`

*Django version: 2.1.5*

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    url_address = models.URLField(
        validators=[RegexValidator('https://www.google.com/.*', message='This is not a Google URL')])
```

Comment: add this `code='invalid_url'` as your last parameter of RegexValidator.

Comment: @Ahtisham this is a solution! Now my custom message is showing when regex check fails.

Comment: did that fixed the problem ?

Comment: @Ahtisham, yes, it is.

Comment: You can accept my edit to your question if you think it makes it better. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `code` as a third parameter to your `RegexValidator`

like this:

```
RegexValidator('https://www.google.com/.*', message='This is not a Google URL', code='invalid_url')
```